# Removing front spaces in a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form, from which the user can enter data ... when the user enters the data in a textbox ..
I want to remove any leading spaces in users data 
and I want to allow user to edit that string from front also..
So how to automatically remove leading spaces in string on `onkeyup` method in javascript and allow user to edit front of string...
searched for long time like all the following

```
    //trim(fname);
//.replace(/\s+/g, '');
//.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    //fname.replace(/^[ ]+|[ ]+$/g,'')
    //fname1.trim();
```

but no use.please any help would be appreciated

Comment: Improve english

Comment: thank you for suggestion ...but I asked about javascript not about english language.....

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `string.trim()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

```
var orig = '   foo  ';
console.log(orig.trim()); // 'foo'

// Another example of .trim() removing whitespace from just one side.

var orig = 'foo    ';
console.log(orig.trim()); // 'foo'
```

in your case, you probably want:

```
fname=fname.trim();
```

Comment: I need to trim string the first spaces under onkeyup method and at the same time allow to add text before the string

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.trim = function () { 
  return this.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g, "");
}
```

the **onkeyup** function does not affect the trim. You just add the **trim** into the  **onkeyup**.

I think you are asking the cursor is not at the end after called the **trim** function  , is it? Please describe the problem clearly...

Comment: I tried this ,,,but according to my need...I wanna edit and add text infront of the string at the same time..

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!